# Beginner: Ajax tutorial is not working

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to learn ajax by using a youtube tutorial.

However, everything I create here does not work out as displayed in the video. I have double-checked the code for several times now.

This is my jsfiddle html code. The js code is in the fiddle (link below)

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<body onload="process()">
Ok, you made it this far...
<br/>
<div id="theD"/>
</body>
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/patrickhaede/K7Tg7/

In the tutorial this is supposed to put out a short text from a txt file in the end. I have tried that on a server and it does not work out there aswell. Also the informations about the states are not given out.

I would really appreciate some help here.

Thanks.

Comment: any JavaScript error return ???

Comment: SyntaxError: missing } after function body

Comment: nothing. When I put those files onto a sever together with the txt file simply nothing happens.

Comment: What tutorial are you following? Sounds like a bad tutorial. You have invalid HTML (`div` is not self-closing).

Comment: and `document.getElementbyId`! not only `getElementById` on line no. *59*

Comment: this makes me crazy. I have been trying around with those tutorials all day and nothing works as shown in the video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hLrlATNa6nE

Comment: Updated JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/K7Tg7/3/ the only error you are getting now is that it cant find the textfile which is logical.

Comment: Hello Rick Hoving. Did I do anything wrong I still dont get any output.

Comment: I posted the wrong link, updated it just a sec ago :-)

Comment: Its working now. Thank you very much. Can you just quickly tell me what was wrong there? Besides the syntax error.

Comment: And one more thing. Actually if I try that on my server (which has the text.txt document) I get the output "undefined" and not the content of the txt file. Is there any solution to that as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another modification of your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/K7Tg7/7/)

```
xmlHttp.open("GET", "/js/beautifier.js", true);
```

Basically the file you are requesting through Ajax must exist on the server. When you request "text.txt" from JSfiddle, no such file is found and you get a 404 status.

Instead of using the /echo/html/ mechanism like pleasedontbelong did, I just picked a file that happens to be present on the JSfiddle server.

The echo/html is a useful tool provided by JSfiddle to simulate Ajax requests, but it could be confusing for beginners.

EDIT:

First of all, the "url" parameter of an Ajax request must be local to the server.

If you try to reference an external URL (even if that URL happens to point to your own site), the XmlHTTPRequest object will report correctly the various phases of request processing, but in the end you will get a status of 0 and an empty contents.

This is a safety feature, to prevent every man and his dog to pester random servers with silly HTTP requests. External access must go through a server first, and only then is JavaScript allowed to retrieve the data.

The way of accessing external URL is to have a server-side script (written in PHP or similar language) access the external data, and then perform an Ajax request on this script.

I think you should familiarize yourself with a few more concepts before trying this.

In the mean time, I advise you to install Apache on your computer, so that you can have a local copy of your site accessable through the `http://localhost` url.

That way, you will have total control over the contents of your site and be able to create whatever files you see fit.

I won't write an Apache installation manual here, so I'm afraid your next step will be to pray the Google God to enlighten you on the mysteries of local Apache server installation :)

Good luck

Comment: my pleasure. Welcome to the network programming world :)

Comment: I have one more issue. I tied to access the text.txt file from my server, but it says "undefined". I did also try the complete link like example.com/folder/folder/text.txt - but that does not work as well.

Answer (score 2):

I update your code below
http://jsfiddle.net/K7Tg7/4/

1. SyntaxError: missing } after function body
2. you should use `document.getElementById()` not `getElementById()`
3. The ajax url is not right if you did't not build a host on your local machine

Comment: thanks. I actually tried a version without the click event on my server and it returned the different states but in the end it only returned "undefined" and not the content in the txt file. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you build a website on your local machine?

Comment: Umm I have it hosted on a webspace. I am not trying to open that locally.

Comment: that is, you should write the full url in javascript, if you can browser you test.txt like this http://www.test.com/text.txt. just replace the test.txt with the full url

Comment: I have also tried that. Do you mean like http://folder/folder/folder/text.txt ???

Answer (score 1):

Stating web dev? welcome to a world of joy and pain!

A few thing on the code: (some of them already mentioned on the comments)

- Do always test your JS in a server (even a local server). If you just open the html file with your browser will block the ajax calls for security reasons.
- Use an IDE with JSLint to prevent syntax errors.
- Always check the browser console for syntax errors, in your case: missing brackets or not defined functions.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes I am a starter and I slowly get used to those hours of trying and trying and trying. I have it on my server and the version that I got from on of the guys here also gives me the output of the different states but in the end it says undefined rather than showing the content of the txt file as it does in the tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hLrlATNa6nE

Comment: Here... http://jsfiddle.net/K7Tg7/6/  You had a typo, you wrote `xmlHttp.responsText`instead of `xmlHttp.responseText`. I had to adapt the request, used POST instead of GET to make it work on jsfiddle